# App on device is different than app on simulator

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I've done my app and it works great on the Corona Simulator, but, once I run it on my device, it doesn't run a bunch of instruction.

These are:

```
function onCollision( event )
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        if event.object1.myName == "ground" and event.object2.myName == "spaceShip" then

                local a = score.get()
                print(a)
                local b = score.load()
                print(b)

                if (a < b) then 
                    best.alpha = 1

                    scoreToBeat.text = score.load()
                    scoreToBeat.alpha = 1

                else 
                    score.save()
                    newRecord.alpha = 1
                end


                timer.cancel(tmrScore)
                gameOver.alpha = 1
                tapToReplay.alpha = 1
                replay.alpha = 0.01
                fade.alpha = 0
                timer.cancel(tmrIS)
                spaceShip.alpha = 1
                if(playEffects) then
                    media.playEventSound( "sounds/gameover.mp3" )
                    playEffects = false
                end
                speed = 0


     end
    end
  end 


 Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
```

Particularly, it performs only "speed = 0" and only the first time I run the app, which means that if I start a new game, it won't even work "speed = 0".

I'm 100% sure that the app is running on the device is the same that runs on the simulator (I tried to change some text).

What can I do?

Comment: What happens when you set the draw mode to 'hybrid' and test it on the device? Are the physics objects being created on the place they were supposed to be?
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/setDrawMode.html

Comment: Add the print statements in each `if/else` block, make sure you run that version on device once more and show the log output from device. And if traceback shows a line number, indicate clearly which line of your posted code that is.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons: the physics not started when get back to scene; the objects aren't dynamic; one of them no longer exists or is no longer a physics object; the handler was removed when game ended and not restarted.

To figure out, add some print statements to see what parts execute:

```
function onCollision( event )
    print 'entered collision'
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        print 'collision began'
        if event.object1.myName == “gd” and event.object2.myName == “hero” then
            print 'collision objects are gd and hero'

            speed = 0

            if (score.get() < score.load()) then   
                print 'score smaller'
                ...

            else 
                print 'score not smaller'
                ...

            end
        else
             print( 'collision objects are', event.object1.myName, event.object2.myName )
        end
    end
end
```

Update:

I had a typo `score = 0`, should have been `speed = 0`.

Comment: Thank you both! I removed the event listener before I leave the scene and it works, anyway alpha values still won't change and I don't know why

Comment: @luaLover I'm confused about "it works" versus "alpha values still won't change": maybe worth updating your question to show updated understanding (such as the messages you get when you run with the added print statements).

Comment: Yes you're right, I try to provide more information. Unfortunately, I don't get any error, and with "it works" I mean that the collision is now detected even if I start a new game, while with "alpha values still won't change" I mean that  

[if (score.get() < score.load()) then ...  newRecord.alpha = 1 end]

is not executed.

Thanks again

Comment: @luaLover OK if it doesn't run either branch then surely the `if gd and hero` condition is false. I've updated with additional print statements, please post console output.

Comment: The console output is 'score smaller' if I don't get and higher score and 'score not smaller' if I get an higher score. Anyway that lines of code work correctly on the simulator, they "just" don't work on the device

Comment: @luaLover  So this is in simulator? There must be away to see console output on device, maybe via android logs: google for "corona console output on device" the first results show how to do this.

Comment: Yes on the simulator works fine, anyway yes there is a way to see console output device and it says "attempt to compare number with nil" on [if (score.get() < score.load()) then ...  print ("score smaller") else print ("score not smaller") end]

Comment: @luaLover I had wrong var score instead of speed, try again; with that typo it surely did not work in sim either, make sure you try first the sim then the device, to guard again this type of mistake again

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch what you mean by "I had wrong var score instead of speed"

Comment: @luaLover The error in log file about "attempt to compare number with nil" was because I had error in my answer, was using "score = 0" whereas in your posted code you have "speed = 0", so you should make sure your code matches my answer then try again on both the sim and device (clearly, only on device once the version on sim works!).

Comment: Ahh yes I've already tried using "speed = 0", but the log file keep saying the error above. Anyway I've updated the original question, and none of the 2 variables ('a' and 'b') seem to be nil (when I print them, they return an int value). However thanks for your constant support :)

Comment: @luaLover if neither a nor b are nil then you can't be getting that error; if you are getting that error, then one of them is nil. Run again. See my comment new to your question.

Comment: I think that the nil variable is "local a = score.get()", because if I print it OUTSIDE of the function it doesn't return any number, but if I print it INSIDE the function it return the correct value (but again only in the simulator). Unfortunately right now I cannot try another solution since I'm not connected with my pc, but as soon as I can (few hours) I will try to find out another way and add another comment.

Comment: UPDATE: now it works, I've added to 'b' "if b == nil then
    b = 0
end" Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Great. It seems like my answer was useful in reaching a solution although not completely but thats OK if it got you partway there you should accept and close at least. Cheers!